# Text is scaling on IE6 even without % and em from View > Text resize function of IE6? see example?

Tags: css, fonts, internet-explorer-6

Text is scaling on IE6 even without % and em from View > Text resize function of IE6?

but on this page http://jitendravyas.com/ nothing is specified in % and em but text is scaling with - View > Text resize function of IE6?

[alt text http://www.homesinhavering.org/media/image/3/n/text_resize_ie_1.jpg](http://www.homesinhavering.org/media/image/3/n/text_resize_ie_1.jpg)

**Why?** Does IE 6support text resizing?

Comment: There are so many `why`s in IE6... The short answer: it's a bad browser. And old. So old.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is considered a major usability and acceptability bug in IE6 - for a long time it was recommended not to use `px` size, as most users will not be able to change it.
Luckily, Microsoft fixed that issue in newer versions of IE.

The mentioned page does not have `%` or `em` (or `ex`, or whatnot), but IE6 supports resizing of *some* text. For example, the page is using:

```
<font size="5">President Clinton: "Y2K may doom us all"</font>
```

Which today is [deprecated](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_FONT.asp).

Another common text size supported by IE6 using CSS is

```
font-size:medium; /*or small, xx-large, etc */
```

Lastly, IE6 will also resize text with *no defined text size at all*. The default text is resizeable.

Here's a sample page for your resizing pleasure: **http://jsbin.com/ozila/2**

Comment: you mean if i will set body {font-size:16px} then text will not resize. and if nothing is specfied or body{font-size:medium} or body {font-size:100%} , text will be resized.

Comment: @Jitendra - Yes, exactly. I added a link so it can be easily tested.